# GIT: Rebase several branches that are on the same "thread"

Tags: git, rebase

I have several branch pointers, with all but one being the parent of another:

```
* <branch Z
| + <branch c
| + _commit 
| + <branch b
| + _commit 
| + <branch a
| + _commit 
|/
+ _commit
```

Is it possible to rebase all them to `branch Z` in one go without rebasing them one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### no

you'll have to rebase each of the branches, which will avoid you errors. I would:

```
git checkout a
git rebase z
git checkout b
git rebase a
git checkout c
git rebase b
```

### workaround

You could however speed things up a bit by not actually rebasing each branch, but not sure it won't make a big difference. You could:

Rebase branch c:

```
git checkout c
git rebase Z
```

now you could forcibly just move the pointers of branches `b` and `a` if you want to avoid the rebasing, but I think this is more error prone:

```
git checkout b
git reset --hard c~2 # 2 commits behind branch c.
git checkout a
git reset --hard b~2 # 2 commits behind branch b.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in one rebase like this:

```
git checkout branchc
git rebase branchz
# if the results look ok:
git branch -f branchb branchc~2
git branch -f brancha branchc~4
```

There is another way to do it in 3 shots:

```
git rebase X brancha
git rebase --onto brancha branchb~2 branchb # rebase only the last 2 commits from branchb
git rebase --onto branchb branchc~2 branchc # rebase only the last 2 commits from branchc
```